# PureCSS grid boxes not 100% height with variable content

Tags: html, css

I am trying to integrate purecss (purecss.io) into wordpress and i have problems setting grid boxes 100% height. I apply a gray background (odd/even nth-child css property) and it clearly shows the problem with variable content inside the boxes.

How do i set the boxes 100% height, so that i can apply background uniformly?

In the screenshot, i want the grid box showing search form to be 100% height so that entire background is gray.

[image]

```html
<widgets class="pure-g">      
<div id="search-2" class="pure-u-1 pure-u-md-1-2 l-box widget widget_search"><form role="search" method="get" id="searchform" class="searchform" action="http://localhost/wp/">
                <div>
                    <label class="screen-reader-text" for="s">Search for:</label>
                    <input type="text" value="" name="s" id="s" />
                    <input type="submit" id="searchsubmit" value="Search" />
                </div>
            </form></div>       <div id="recent-posts-2" class="pure-u-1 pure-u-md-1-2 l-box widget widget_recent_entries">     <h2>Recent Posts</h2>       <ul>
                    <li>
                <a href="http://localhost/wp/index.php/2015/08/25/wordpress-themes-are-just-being-released-today/">WordPress themes are just being released today all over the World 1200 GMT</a>
                        </li>
                    <li>
                <a href="http://localhost/wp/index.php/2015/08/24/hello-world/">Hello world!</a>
                        </li>
                    <li>
                <a href="http://localhost/wp/index.php/2013/01/11/markup-html-tags-and-formatting/">Markup: HTML Tags and Formatting</a>
                        </li>
                    <li>
                <a href="http://localhost/wp/index.php/2013/01/10/markup-image-alignment/">Markup: Image Alignment</a>
                        </li>
                    <li>
                <a href="http://localhost/wp/index.php/2013/01/09/markup-text-alignment/">Markup: Text Alignment</a>
                        </li>
                </ul>
        </div>
</widgets>
```

I apply gray background color to odd widgets with this css code

```css
/** Front page widgets ***/

.widget {   font-size: 1.7vw; }

.gray { background: #eee;  }


.widget img {
display:block;
margin: 20px;
}

.widget:nth-child(odd) { background: #eee }

.widget p { overflow:hidden; margin-left: 2em; display: block }


.widget h2 { margin:0; padding-bottom: 0.7em }
```

Comment: please do this: open your webpage at browser, right click on it, select view source, copy the whole source code and paste it here.

Comment: The code does not reproduce the depicted result, meaning we cannot help you. I have tried adding pure's library in a `link` tag and changed the css, but still does not yield the same result. You must have forgotten to include something somewhere.

Comment: `<widgets>` is not a correct html element. Use `<div>` instead

Comment: @pbu have you checked my answer?? its working.. do you want something else?? or your problem is gone??

Comment: @pbu why don't you apply the min-height to the div by calculating in jquery that will solve your problem,??? just calculate current height and apply min-height to that div

Comment: @pbu and is your css showing proper as shown in the screen shot,>

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is an excellent use case for [flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout). Just set the `display` property of the parent of the grid elements to `flex`, like so:

```
.pure-g {
  display: flex;
}
```

And the heights of the grid elements will be normalized.

As others have suggested already, you might also be able to achieve similar results by setting the `display` properties of involved elements to their respective table counterparts, essentially turning your grid into a fake table.

Other than that there's no way to normalize column heights with CSS without taking (one of) the elements out the content flow, which may not be desired.

In CSS, `height: 100%` doesn't quite behave as one would expect. Any percentual height won't resolve to an actual height unless their direct parent has as explicit `height` declared, but since you have dynamic content height you cannot/should not set a static value.

You could work around this by using javascript to dynamically set the `height` of the parent to the height of the tallest child, thus making percentual heights work inside of it, but that's an entirely different question.

Comment: setting height using `vh` units solves this issue, ex: `height: 100vh`

Comment: @dave.mcalpine you cannot replace percentage with vh for this sort of thing.

Answer (score 1):

Here I've got a way to do this, *first make those divs **`display: table-cell`***. **This will make them go equal `height`**. And for responsiveness of your website at lower mobile resolutions, you can use **`@media` query to set the divs back to `display: block`**

See the [live example](http://jsfiddle.net/vdqm1cq2/) what I mean.

You will see both the divs at equal `height` due to `display: table-cell`, but when you will *drag the left border of the Result window to make its width smaller* then you will see at **window width: 500px** they break on next line. You can also fully control this behavior as you want.

```
#search-2, #recent-posts-2 { /* or you can simply use .widget here */
    padding: 20px;
    display: table-cell;
}

@media all and (max-width: 500px) {
    #search-2, #recent-posts-2 {
        display: block;
    }
}
```

Comment: i tried this but it breaks the pure css grids. have you tested using the purecss code?

Comment: @pbu it breaks on lower resolution, that's what I did using `@media query` just for the grids to look good on lower resolution.

Answer (score 1):

```
widget {
  display: table;
}
#search-2, #recent-posts-2 {
  display: table-cell;
}
```

Working fiddle
https://jsfiddle.net/bj1kqn6k/4/

Comment: Please check again: https://jsfiddle.net/bj1kqn6k/5/. I have updated adding CSS sheet. It still breaks. It should have 2 cols

Comment: When you on responsive?

Comment: Yes, you should only style the `.widgets` class. i removed the substyles. check now.

Answer (score 1):

This will Work,
HTML

```
<div class="pure-g hellodiv">   

<div id="search-2" class="pure-u-1 pure-u-md-1-2 l-box widget widget_search"><form role="search" method="get" id="searchform" class="searchform" action="http://localhost/wp/">
                <div>
                    <label class="screen-reader-text" for="s">Search for:</label>
                    <input type="text" value="" name="s" id="s" />
                    <input type="submit" id="searchsubmit" value="Search" />
                </div>
            </form>
    </div>       

    <div id="recent-posts-2" class="pure-u-1 pure-u-md-1-2 l-box widget widget_recent_entries">     <h2>Recent Posts</h2>       <ul>
                    <li>
                <a href="http://localhost/wp/index.php/2015/08/25/wordpress-themes-are-just-being-released-today/">WordPress themes are just being released today all over the World 1200 GMT</a>
                        </li>
                    <li>
                <a href="http://localhost/wp/index.php/2015/08/24/hello-world/">Hello world!</a>
                        </li>
                    <li>
                <a href="http://localhost/wp/index.php/2013/01/11/markup-html-tags-and-formatting/">Markup: HTML Tags and Formatting</a>
                        </li>
                    <li>
                <a href="http://localhost/wp/index.php/2013/01/10/markup-image-alignment/">Markup: Image Alignment</a>
                        </li>
                    <li>
                <a href="http://localhost/wp/index.php/2013/01/09/markup-text-alignment/">Markup: Text Alignment</a>
                        </li>
                </ul>
        </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
html,body{height:100%;margin:0 auto;}
.hellodiv {
  display: table;background-color:red;height:100%;
}
#search-2, #recent-posts-2 {
  display: table-cell;
}
/** Front page widgets ***/

.widget {   font-size: 1.7vw; }

.gray { background: #eee;  }


.widget img {
display:block;
margin: 20px;
}

.widget:nth-child(odd) { background: #eee }

.widget p { overflow:hidden; margin-left: 2em; display: block }


.widget h2 { margin:0; padding-bottom: 0.7em }
```

Comment: Nope not working! I wrapped the widgets with div and added the hellodiv class.

Answer (score 1):

Some times to have such a layout, you need `absolute` or `fixed` positioning, I would go for fixed, since the `div` will always remain full height:

`.widget_search {
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    bottom:0;
    width:15em;
}`

Answer (score 1):

Add below custom css in your css.

```css
.pure-g {
  display: table;
  table-layout: fixed;
}
.widget {
  font-size: 1.7vw;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Comment: and also add  #search-2, #recent-posts-2 { display: table-cell;}

Comment: You should add this information to your post, not as a comment, if it is fully part of your answer.

Answer (score 1):

This can be achieved with flex-box. https://jsfiddle.net/pt9q18j9/

there are two parts to flexbox, the container and the items in the container

set your container, in this case `widgets` to be `display:flex;`

```
widgets{
  display: flex;
}
```

then the items you want to display side by side get the `flex-basis` property. setting a value of 1 on each means they will default to being the same size, if you set something like 1 for search and 2 for entries, entries would attempt to take up twice the space

```
.widget .widget_search {
  flex-basis: 1;   
}
.widget .widget_recent_entries {
  flex-basis: 1; 
}
```

this is a very good article on flex-box https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/