# CSS Flexbox (Grid): Child objects height 100% in Chrome

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm using flexbox grid and want to align an item vertically center. With the following code, it's working at IE and Firefox, but not at Chrome. The problem is, that the .parent Element has not the height of 100% in Chrome. Any ideas? Thank you.

```
.parent {
  height:100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: center;
  background-color:orange;
}

.child {
  width:100%;
  flex: 1;
  background-color:yellow;
}
```

...

```
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-6 col">
  <div id="c19" class="parent">
    <div class="child">
      <h3>test</h3>
      <p>quiate re odis rem endignam quam autempos aspel il inis as il ipsam ve aspel il inis ui utassi tem quiatent et aut occatintio. Urempel itaqui a nis aliquas velendere</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: fyi: the .col element ist height:100% in all testet browsers...

Comment: I didn't anything `vertical-align:center` https://jsfiddle.net/qsjbw3jy/

Comment: Change the `height` on `.parent` from `height: 100%` to `height: 100vh`. [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0s43rwc0/)

Comment: Does the parent div of `.parent`have a height set? If not, relative height values will not work.

Comment: not working for me, because now the height has browserheight and not the height of its parent. :/

Comment: no, the .parent element is an dynamic element, which grows with its content

Comment: I don't get your problem then. The content will always be centered vertically, if `.parent` and `.col-` grow with it. The code you provided here looks the same in every browser: http://codepen.io/wilmaknattern/pen/vGLwNO

Comment: Its an 2 column layout, the right column is tall as the left column. And the content in the right column should be vertically centered. (the left content is higher than the right one)

Comment: I could change the title to: Childelement Height of flexbox grid column should be 100%. (same height as .col)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PureCSS grid boxes not 100% height with variable content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32740819/purecss-grid-boxes-not-100-height-with-variable-content)

Answer (score 0):

Add **min-height** to your .parent class. like below

```
.parent{
  height:100%;
  min-height:200px;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think I found a solution, it's now working at IE, FF, Chrome:

```
.col {
  position:relative;
}

.parent {
  position:absolute;
  bottom:0px;
  left:0px;
  top:0px;
  right:0px;
  background-color:orange;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: center;
}

.child {
    background-color:yellow;
}
```

Comment: But not at Safari :(((
...and the customer is using Safari as main browser ;O

Comment: sorry...it's working at Safari on mac, I tested it at safari for windows and that isn't supported for windows anymore since version 5.x